# How to set form input value in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, forms, input

how to set a value for an input form in angularjs?

this is my input form:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="John" ng-model="dataOrang.nama">
```

Comment: What ever you type will gets stored in $scope.dataOrang.nama

Comment: thanks, thats work

Answer (score 4):

You can set value in controller like below.

```
$scope.dataOrang = {
        nama : "SomeValue"
    }
```

Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9233/

Answer (score 2):

Add these in an controller,
**$scope.dataOrang.nama = "Sample Data"**

Answer (score 0):

**ng-value** = Specifies the value of an input element.
**ng-model** = Binds the value of HTML controls to application data.

```js
var app = angular.module( "myApp", [] );

app.controller( "myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {

    // set value from app to input html
    $scope.value = {
        nama: "Doe"
    };

}] );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <input type="text" placeholder="John" ng-model="model.nama" ng-value="value.nama" />     

    <!-- get value from input html into p tag -->
    <p>Nama: {{ model.nama }}</p>

</div>
```